# How to test a custom global exception page for azure ad b2c?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am using custom policies and I have defined the location of the custom exception page as follows:

```
<ContentDefinition Id="api.error">
        <LoadUri>https://{Settings:BlobStorageAccount}.blob.core.windows.net/{Settings:BlobContainer}/html/global_exception.html</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:globalexception:1.2.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Error page</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>
```

However, how do you go about triggering an internal API exception within Azure AD B2C to see this page in action? I tried also using a default user policy and adjust the location but there doesn't seem to be a way to view the page that way as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `client_id` parameter in the authorization request to an unknown value where this should display the error page with the following text:

```
AADB2C90018: The client id '<client_id>' specified in the request is not registered in tenant '<your_tenant_name>.onmicrosoft.com'.
```